# With a known secret key, can I determine the response for an authentication challenge?

Tags: authentication

I am trying to find a response for a 64-bit authentication challenge message (e.g. c055258b829d89bc).  Each challenge message is unique.

If I know the 512-bit secret key that was used to create the 64-bit challenge message, is it possible to find the response?  If so, how would one go about doing so?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea which authentication scheme you refer too. But usually a challenge-response authentication scheme is used to prove that the client knows a specific secret. So the information about the secret are not contained in the challenge (which is often random) but instead in the response. But the exact details depend on the authentication scheme so you need to provide more details if you want to have a better answer.